# How can I persist cached tables in memory after the program ends (Apache Spark)?

Tags: mapreduce, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to Apache Spark and have a simple question about DataFrame caching.

When I cached a DataFrame in memory using `df.cache()` in python, I found that the data is removed after the program terminates.

Can I keep the cached data in memory so that I can access the data for the next run without doing `df.cache()` again?

Comment: do you mean that you want to write in on disk? in what format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache used with `cache()` is tied to the current spark context; its purpose is to prevent having to recalculate some intermediate results in the current application multiple times. If the context gets closed, the cache is gone. Nor can you share the cache between different running Spark contexts.

To be able to reuse the data in a different context, you will have to save it to a file system. If you prefer the results to be in memory (or have a good chance of being in memory when you try to reload them) you can look at using [Tachyon](http://www.tachyon-project.org).

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about saving the RDD into disk , use any of the following -

[image]

The link is for pyspark , same is available for Java/ Scala as well-#

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

If you were not talking about disk , then cache() is already doing the job of saving the same in memory